# How to set actual HTML signature on Outlook 2019 for OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I've followed the tutorials online that tell me to open the HTML file of the signature using a web browser, copy its content, and throw it into the signature GUI window on Outlook. I lost a lot of formatting, though. Any better way of achieving this by having Outlook parse the actual HTML file I have?

[This app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/html-email-signature-for-outlook/id1101267774?mt=12) says it does it, for example. I want to be able to do the same.

Comment: For your reference: https://emailsignaturerescue.com/support/all-supported-software/macos/outlook-mac-2019/how-to-install-a-html-email-signature-in-outlook-mac-2019